# Android Live Wallpaper crashes when tap on camera

Tags: android, camera, crash, live-wallpaper

I have a live wallpaper that just draws triangles, very simple, and runs smoothly all time. After testing found that when I open the camera to take pictures the phone freezes for about 10 seconds, then the camera opens and the wallpaper crashes and the message "Unfortunately, Live Wallpaper has stopped." appears. Also found that when I open any barcode scanner app the problem raises again because the scanner uses the camera too.  Seems the problem raises when the camera app runs. Any ideas what's causing it?

Answer (score 0):

hi @Bullet Camera is just open ones, if it open through any other apps then, you can can not access your camera, Solution is that, where you use camera please release that  after no used.

main problem is that, in your app (app in that you are using camera) , so , you release camera after used.

like following :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

when you need

```
private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

or

```
public void stopCamera() {

    if (cameraDevice != null) {
        cameraDevice.stopPreview();
        cameraDevice.setPreviewCallback(null);
        cameraDevice.release();
        cameraDevice = null;
        System.out.println("in to the stop video");
    }

}
```